# How can I make posts from my app shareable?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I've written an app which will allow my website to automatically post certain updates to my facebook wall, and from the documentation I know that passing in values for the parameters picture, link, name, caption and description (plus of course the access_token) to /me/feed I can create a post.

My question though is how can I make this post "shareable", i.e. add a "share" link to the right of the already existing "like" and "comment" links?

I've searched around the graph API documentation on facebook and I can't find the answers, but if there is a documentation page that answers my questions then I'd be grateful if somebody could point me to it, because I'm fairly sure it will answer other questions that I haven't even thought of yet!